# Passing dynamic select values to pop up link Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

I have a select dropdown. When user makes a selection it opens a confirmation pop up with the same selection in it. After clicking Submit, it opens a new window with the target link.

This works fine in Safari, Chrome, Opera. Firefox (and IE apparently) opens a blank window. Any ideas why?

```
<a href="javascript:if(document.getElementById('listUpdate').value) window.open(document.getElementById('listUpdate').value);" target="_blank">Submit</a>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pw8w1x6d/8/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using the below instead:

```
<a href="javascript:if(document.getElementById('listUpdate').value) window.open(document.getElementById('listUpdate','_blank').value);">Submit</a>
```